# Blockquote doesn't work for iOS log

Tags: bug

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21895674/edit and try to blockquote the log at the end of the post, this:

```
> 'View item (<UIImageView: 0x10aaa0c70; frame = (15 175; 288 42);
> autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x10aa7e0a0>>) should be a descendant of reference view in
> <UIDynamicAnimator: 0x10ae17610> Stopped (0.000000s) in <UIView:
> 0x10aa9e1e0> {{0, 0}, {288, 195}}'
```

which renders as:

> 'View item (>) should be a descendant of reference view in
>    Stopped (0.000000s) in  {{0, 0}, {288, 195}}'

A `(>)` appears instead of a big part of the log. Or simply start editing this post and see the original text behind the `(>)`. Blockquote should work as code quote: displaying raw text without any processing.

Comment: Why do you even need to blockquote that error message?

Comment: This happens since the Markdown syntax on SO is HTML aware. There are not many options here. You can put them between backticks, or HTML escape `<` and `>` in the message.

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote should work as code quote: displaying raw text without any processing.

No it should not. A blockquote works exactly as regular text, because it is just regular text. The only difference is that it signifies that this part of the text is **quoted** from other sources. There is no reason why the quoted text should behave as a code block.

You should format that error message either as code block, or as code block inside a quote if you must:

> ```
> >     Error message starts here
> >     and can span multiple lines
> >     and even <contain special characters>
> ```